# Possible values of the solution to an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Problem: $y'(t)\cos(y(t))=1, -1<t<1$, when $y(0)=0$, find $y(\sqrt2/2)$.

This differential equation is equivalent to $dt=\cos(y(t))dy$. By integrating both sides and using the initial condition $y(0)=0$, we have $t=\sin(y(t))$, then it yields two answers $y(\sqrt2/2)=\pi/4$ and $y(\sqrt2/2)=3\pi/4$ and many others. But it seems to me the solution to this differential equation should be unique, so how to explain this situation?

Comment: Once you have $t=\sin(y(t)),$ is not $y(t)=\arcsin t?$

Comment: @mfl I think the value of $y(t)$ is not limited to $(-\pi/2, +\pi/2)$

Comment: It's nonlinear, so there is no guarantee of uniqueness.

Comment: Do you mean the domain?

Comment: @mfl Yes. By taking inverse, they could look like $y(t)=\arcsin t+C$

Comment: If you add the constant in the other side then it would be $y(t)=\arcsin(t+c).$ Now use $y(0)=0$ to get $c=n\pi.$ But $\sqrt{2}/2\in (0,\pi).$ So, $n=0.$ That is $c=0.$

Comment: Kaynex: To get a unique solution (Picard-Lindelöf theorem) you only need that the secant is Lipschitz-continuous.